# How to add System.Data.SqlClient nuget package into .Net Portable (PCL)4.5 profile

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, dll

I am writing a crossplatform (iOS and android) Xamarin app and I need a sql connection to my database. I found out that I need System.Data.SqlClient to achieve this. But when I try to add System.Data.SqlClient to my core project I get:

> Could not install package 'System.Data.SqlClient 4.4.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I get that apparently this .NETPortable version is compatible, but what is the solution to this? There must be a way to access a SQL database. Also I found that other posts asked to add System.Data first, but this package doesn't even show up in nuget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case that you change your pcl project into .NET Standard you should be able to install this nuget package.

Follow this awesome [snack pack](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/Snack-Pack-15-Upgrading-to-XamarinForms-to-NET-Standard)!

In Visual Studio Preview there is template to create xamarin project using .netstandard. I can confirm that it works.

Comment: Sorry about the late response. This seemed to have worked great, though it required a fair bit of messing around with visual studio name spaces and the like. Thanks a lot. I still don't really understand how it can require this much to allow for a sql connection. Seems like a quite normal use case.

Comment: There is definitely another way then using this nuget package. The .NetStandard allows you to use all these packages that you couldn't use it in pcl before.